# Ensure value is substring of other value

Tags: ansible

Assume the following variables:

```yaml
cron_d:
  script:
    - src: xfa.sh.j2
      dest: /opt/xfb_abc.sh
    - src: xfa.sh.j2
      dest: /opt/xfa_abc.sh
  cron:
    - name: agbcc
      job: /opt/xfa_abc.sh
    - name: aaaagbcc
      job: /opt/me.sh
```

My goal is to have at least one value of `cron_d.script.dest` be a substring of `cron_d.cron.job`.

I currently have this code, but that only fully matches the string, instead of only a substring.

```yaml
- name: assert that each script name matches at least once with a job name
  assert:
    that: 
      - "'{{ item.dest }}' in job_list"
  vars:
    job_list: "{{ cron_d.cron | map(attribute='job') | list }}"
  loop: "{{ cron_d.script }}"
```

I'd like extend that, so that the value of `dest` must be present in the `job`, but the job might contain more characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be reduced to the problem:

Q: ***"Each item of *dest* must be a substring of at least one item from *jobs*."***

```yaml
  jobs: [aaa, bbb, ccc, abc]
  dest: [aa, bc, xx]
```

A: Create the below dictionary

```yaml
  results: |
    {% filter from_yaml %}
    {% for i in dest %}
    {{ i }}: [{% for j in jobs %}{{ i in j }},{% endfor %}]
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfilter %}
```

gives

```yaml
  results:
    aa: [true, false, false, false]
    bc: [false, false, false, true]
    xx: [false, false, false, false]
```

Test it

```yaml
    - assert:
        that: item.value is any
        success_msg: "[OK]  {{ item.key }} is a substring of some jobs."
        fail_msg: "[ERR] {{ item.key }} is not a substring of any job."
      loop: "{{ results|dict2items }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: '[OK]  aa is a substring of some jobs.'
  msg: '[OK]  bc is a substring of some jobs.'
  msg: '[ERR] xx is not a substring of any job.'
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    jobs: [aaa, bbb, ccc, abc]
    dest: [aa, bc, xx]

    results: |
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {% for i in dest %}
      {{ i }}: [{% for j in jobs %}{{ i in j }},{% endfor %}]
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfilter %}

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: results|to_yaml

    - assert:
        that: item.value is any
        success_msg: "[OK]  {{ item.key }} is a substring of some jobs."
        fail_msg: "[ERR] {{ item.key }} is not a substring of any job."
      loop: "{{ results|dict2items }}"
```